# ASP.Net Identity Changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have been using the following video from Microsoft to help me get started on my applications:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJ4WyOJ2oKc&feature=youtu.be&t=28m43s

I have built several applications using this method. I just created a new application yesterday and I'm no longer able to complete most of the steps in this video. The template no longer shows an AccountController, or the Views folder. I've also noticed that many of the other files, i.e. bundle.config have been moved to new directories.

I wasn't aware there were any changes made, nor have I updated Visual Studio. I'm trying to figure out what happened, and how I am supposed to work with the new "changes". I haven't been able to find any new videos that explain how to complete things now.

All I am trying to do right now, is what he is showing in the video, about changing the username. Right now in the Register action, both UserName and Email are set to model.Email.

I need to change those lines, but apparently they don't even exist anymore.

**Directories**
Account,
App_Data,
App_Start,
Content,
Fonts,
Models,
Scripts,

[image]

Comment: What new directories are you seeing?

Comment: I've uploaded a screen shot [here](http://i57.tinypic.com/334868k.png). You can also see that bundle.config is in the root directory, and it never used to be there. It used to be in App_Start.

Comment: I'm not seeing any new directories, but the template is no longer including directories like View, or files like AccountController. I've started over a couple times, and this is what I get as the default setup.

Comment: Your picture isn't loading for me. Please edit the directory details into your question.

Comment: Are you able to see them now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the web application project, make sure you select MVC for the templates. That will ensure you get the controllers folder etc. Then to make sure Identity gets installed, select "Individual Accounts" for the authentication type.

Comment: @Choatech In VS 2015 on the New Web Application page you have a choice between using ASP.NET 4.6 or a preview of ASP.NET 5. For the moment, ASP.NET 4.6 is the correct choice because Identity hasn't been implemented yet in ASP.NET 5.